# Laravel 4 Former::checkbox() always checked

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having an issue with the Laravel 4 Package [Former](http://anahkiasen.github.io/former/) and the use of checkboxes. I'm trying to Former::populate() a user edit form within a blade template but my checkboxes are always checked.

**Here is my current code:**

{{ Former::checkbox('is_admin')->text('Is Admin?'); }}

**I've tried:**

```
{{ Former::checkbox('is_admin')->text('Is Admin?')->check(false); }}
```

and

```
{{ Former::checkbox('is_admin')->text('Is Admin?')->forceValue(false); }}
```

To no avail.

My database field 'is_admin' is a boolean field. I thought maybe Former didn't like 1s and 0s but it doesn't uncheck my checkboxes even if I set a getter to return false.

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Wait...so what happens if its just {{ Former::checkbox('is_admin')->text('Is Admin?')}}

Comment: Kyle, it remains checked even though the DB field value is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug with Former.. Keep in mind it looks like you can overrule whatever happened with populate with populateField.

Comment: Definite bug. Unfortunately brought up 4 months ago with no current update. Here is the issue on github: https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former/issues/60

Comment: Thanks John, it looks like a 0 or false is considered a value and the checkbox is checked. I had to overrule the value with populateField and set the value to Null for it to uncheck.

Comment: Ah ok sounds good, good to know.. I'm tempted to try out Former since this populate functionality and some of the other goodies look really nice.. but it's a little discouraging to see such long-running issues. The author does look to still be active in merging pull requests at least.